# installation of TeX Live and Mathtype

Tags: texlive

I am documenting a project using TeX Live.There are few mathematical expressions to be included. I am using Mathtype for writing expressions. Can anyone tell me how to link both Mathtype and TeX Live?

Comment: There is no need to use MathType; LaTeX has full builtin support for mathematics.

Comment: mathtype is perhaps not the first choice of editor for typing ltex but I believe it does have an export tex option. You don't "link" the two programs you would just cut and paste the exported latex expression as plain text, adding to you latex document as required.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by David, Mathtype doesn't export as such (hence no export button). But there is `cut and copy` facilility. To configure this go to  <kbd>Preferences</kbd>  →  <kbd>Cut and Copy Preferences</kbd>.

[image]

The following window opens:

[image]

Here Choose (check) <kbd>MathML or TeX</kbd> and in the following drop down field choose
 <kbd>latex 2.09 and later</kbd> . Press OK and start typing your equation in Mathtype. Once you are done, select the equation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

and copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>). Now go to your tex editor and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) to get something like this:

```
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyraiabg2
% da9iaad2gacaWGJbWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaaa!3A89!
\[E = m{c^2}\]
```

The metadata can be switched off by un-checking the `Include MahtType data in translation`
in `MathML or TeX` options (the second figure).

But I recommend that one learn typing these LaTeX codes directly to get the equations and I believe that this will be very helpful in the long run.